# Design question-offline web application

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a requirement to design an offline web application

The requirement goes like this,

**Current aplication**
Its a .net web application collect surveys from users.

**New requirement**
When web server is not available we have to give the user an option to fill the survey offline and later submit it when the server is connected.

What are the dot net techniques you suggest to achieve this.

i invite a discussion on the pros and cons side also.

**Example**

Excel sheet uploading was one possible option .But while entering data validation is required.

If i use a smart client application its not possible to ask every user to insatll it on their system.

Does any advance dot net features allow me to do this?

Thanks in advance
SA

Comment: [Read this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GoogleGearsMaybeAllRichInternetApplicationsNeededWasLocalStorageAndAnOfflineMode.aspx) on Google Gears and .Net. I think it should get you started

Answer (score 0):

I assume the ClickOnce comment relates to people without the full .NET framework (or different operating systems).

Depending on the timescales, you could look at Silverlight 3... this has an [offline/out-of-browser](http://nerddawg.blogspot.com/2009/03/introducing-offline-and-out-of-browser.html) capability very similar to ClickOnce; this might give you more coverage and a great UI too...

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET has a concept of isolated storage. You can use this concept intellegiently to achieve what you want.

Some links [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IsolatedStorage.aspx).

Comment: will you please eplain how is this concept used for offline applications? i need a storage in the client side like google gear